# Como somar valor de variáveis com o valor de uma variável salva no userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3

vou tentar ser objetivo, preciso salvar uma variável que o valor que estiver guardado dentro vai ser o texto de uma label e esse valor é alterado quando é realizado um input de outra variável. Por exemplo:

Variável saldo tem o valor de 50.0, o usuário consegue realizar um input que é salvo na variável recarga, vamos dizer que o valor da recarga foi 70.0, então eu preciso que seja calculado ao valor já existente na variável saldo e atualizar o label, que no caso ficaria em 120.0.

Não tenho muita experiência com OO e estou com muitas dificuldades, acredito que preciso ler primeiro o valor salvo no userdefaults da variável saldo e depois incrementar com o valor da variável recarga, desculpa se estiver sendo leigo demais, alguém poderia me dar uma direção? Pois o usuário conseguir realizar varias recargas e nisso o valor do saldo é alterado

Answer (score 1):

***Ficaria mais ou menos assim...***

```
var saldo = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 

let valorInicial = "50" 
saldo.setObject(valorInicial, forKey: "Valor")

//Salve a informação 
saldo.synchronize()


//Carregar Informação
var VL = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let Dados = VL.objectForKey("Valor")
//Some os valores e converta
var inteiros = Int(Dados) + Int(input.text) //input é o nome do campo que o 
//usuário irá digitar o segundo valor.

print(Inteiros)



//Make some changes
let novoValor = Inteiros
NV.setObject(novoValor, forKey: "Update")
//Lembre de salvar
NV.synchronize()
```